# Angular - Get JSON data from CodeIgniter

Tags: php, json, angular, codeigniter

I'm trying to get JSON data from my CodeIgniter 3 project, where it only throws JSON data like this:

```
class Get_data extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('url_helper');
    }

    public function users()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
        $row = $query->result_array();

        echo json_encode($row);
    }
```

If you access the link, for example, `http://192.168.1.5/codeigniter/get_data/users`, it will display the result like this:

> [{"userID":"2","username":"3-D"},{"userID":"3","username":"3Com"},{"userID":"4","username":"3D"},{"userID":"5","username":"3KVA"},{"userID":"6","username":"3M"},{"userID":"7","username":"A4Tech"}]

And I've created an Angular app inside my CodeIgniter project (*please guide me if I put my angular app in the right directory, or should I put it in a separate directory*).

```
/htdocs
    /codeigniter
        /angular-app <-- my Angular app
        /application
        /system
        /user_guide
```

Then I try to access the data like this. I first created a `user.ts`file that declares variables (*please guide me again if this is needed*):

```
export class User {
    userID: number;
    username: string;
}
```

Then I created a service that gets the data:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {

    constructor(private http:Http) {
    }

    getUsers() { 
        return this.http.get('http://192.168.1.5/codeigniter/get_data/users')
               .map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

Then I try to open my Angular app using port 4201. And open my browser to `http://192.168.1.5:4201`.

It is working when I use Microsoft Edge. But when I use Google Chrome, I get this error:

> Failed to load http://192.168.1.5/codeigniter/get_data/users: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.10.101:4201' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to the request

Comment: Does it have any security issue if I does that?

Comment: this is the standard header you need to add for CORS

Comment: Do you need to run your Angular front-end on a different port?

Comment: @RahulSingh that is simply terrible advice. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a **response** header

Comment: @Phil - My CodeIgniter project runs on port 80 and my Angular app runs on different port (e.g., 4200 or 4201).